# How can I add a comma in a variable data?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to remove `key` and added `comma` after each value, I have tired with `foreach` but i coundn't sucuss.

```
$data = array:195 [▼
          0 => 26404.759765625
          1 => 26390.619140625
          2 => 26391.9609375
          3 => 26397.6796875
          4 => 26421.630859375
          5 => 26414.880859375
          6 => 26409.33984375
          7 => 26410.509765625
          8 => 26403.220703125
          9 => 26386.029296875
          10 => 26400.109375
          11 => 26412.369140625
          12 => 26408.099609375
          13 => 26418.029296875
          14 => 26422.80078125
```

I am trying with below loop :

```
foreach($data  as $key=>$value){
$dataes = $value
}
DD($dataes);
```

**expected result** should be like below:

```
    array:195 [▼
         26404.759765625,
         26390.619140625,
         26391.9609375,
         26397.6796875,
    so on...
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove key ? It does not make sense. Array needs keys. For display purpose, you can simply use values from the array

Comment: Are you trying to echo (output) the data comma separated?

Comment: It really just sounds like you want `implode(",\n", $data)`

Comment: I am trying to add comman for value as expected result.. i want that result @MadhurBhaiya

Answer (score 2):

To echo the data comma separated you can use implode which takes an array and uses the "glue" between each array item and builds a string of it.

```
echo implode(",<br>", $data);
```

This will give you one item per line and a comma after each item.

Here you can see the output of the code.
https://3v4l.org/AHvu3C
Notice that this is a command line so html will show up as text.
Running the same code on a PHP interpreter and browser will make it correct html.

---

Since you have are making an API I assume json_encode is what you need.
Json_encode returns an array as a string that can be received and decoded easily.

```
echo json_encode( $data);
//[26404.759765625,26390.619140625,26391.9609375,26397.6796875,26421.630859375,26414.880859375,26409.33984375,26410.509765625,26403.220703125,26386.029296875,26400.109375,26412.369140625,26408.099609375,26418.029296875,26422.80078125]
```

https://3v4l.org/6MMZu

Comment: `<br>` is html. And if you run it in a browser with html running it should give you a new line. This is basic html 1.0 from early 1990's or something. Trust me it works.

Comment: actually i am not going to run in hmtl but. i am making api for `laravel charts package`

Comment: *facepalm*,ok... What are you expecting then?

Comment: i want only comma and remove key which ... `implode(",", $data);` is worked for me

Comment: If you are making an API then why not use the standardized method of `json_encode`?

Answer (score 1):

To simply get the output as comma separated, you can use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function.

```
string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )
```

> Returns a string containing a string representation of all the array
>   elements in the same order, with the glue string between each element.

Try the following code:

```
// convert the $data array into a string
// It takes elements of the array, and join them with a comma (our input) 
// and, returns a string
$string = implode(',', $data);

// just display the string
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to do:

```
$dataes[] = implode(",\n", $data);
```

This concatenates the values of the $data in one string (with new lines).

Comment: This returns a string, OP wants an array.

Comment: Why create an array with one string. Not my downvote though

Comment: Looks to me that the expected result is an array.